# Pandas Mean for Certain Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like that:

[image]

How can I able to calculate mean (min/max, median) for specific column if Cluster==1 or CLuster==2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create new df with only the relevant rows, using:

```
newdf = df[df['cluster'].isin([1,2)]

newdf.mean(axis=1)
```

In order to calc mean of a specfic column you can:

```
newdf["page"].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: I think you need to average over `axis=0` not 1, no?

Comment: never mind, you're right I thought you're doing the `.mean` first and then picking the column

Comment: @evan54 you were right actually for computing on the specific column it should be `axis=0` otherwise you get `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` so after double-checking I edited the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you meant take the mean only where Cluster is 1 or 2, then the other answers here address your issue.  If you meant take a separate mean for each value of Cluster, you can use pandas' aggregation functions, including `groupyby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby("Cluster").mean()
```

is the simplest and will take means of all columns, grouped by Cluster.

```
df.groupby("Cluster").agg({"duration" : np.mean})
```

is an example where you are taking the mean of just one specific column, grouped by cluster. You can also use `np.min`, `np.max`, `np.median`, etc.

The `groupby` method produces a `GroupBy` object, which is something like but not like a `DataFrame`.  Think of it as the `DataFrame` grouped, waiting for aggregation to be applied to it. The `GroupBy` object has simple built-in aggregation functions that apply to all columns (the `mean()` in the first example), and also a more general aggregation function (the `agg()` in the second example) that you can use to apply specific functions in a variety of ways.  One way of using it is passing a `dict` of column names keyed to functions, so specific functions can be applied to specific columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line, using [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). For example you can do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# This will just produce an example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(30), 'Cluster':np.ones(30,dtype=np.int)})
df.loc[10:19, "Cluster"] *= 2
df.loc[20:,   "Cluster"] *= 3

# This line is all you need
df.loc[(df['Cluster']==1)|(df['Cluster']==2), 'a'].mean()
```

The boolean indexing array is `True` for the correct clusters. `a` is just the name of the column to compute the mean over.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple intuitive answer

First pick the rows of interest, then average then pick the columns of interest.

```
clusters_of_interest = [1, 2]
columns_of_interest = ['page']

# rows of interest
newdf = df[ df.CLUSTER.isin(clusters_of_interest) ]
# average and pick columns of interest
newdf.mean(axis=0)[ columns_of_interest ]
```

### More advanced

```
# Create groups object according to the value in the 'cluster' column
grp = df.groupby('CLUSTER')
# apply functions of interest to all cluster groupings
data_agg = grp.agg( ['mean' , 'max' , 'min' ] )
```

This is also a good [link](http://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/) which describes aggregation techniques. It should be noted that the "simple answer" averages over clusters 1 AND 2 or whatever is specified in the `clusters_of_interest` while the `.agg` function averages over each group of values having the same `CLUSTER` value.